# Inserting part of a value from one field into another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working within one table of a MS Access DB. I would like to use an iif statement to determine if a value from Field A conforms to a valid format (in this case, either one or two numbers followed by a letter). If it does, I would like to take just the numeric portion of Field A (e.g., if an entry for Field A is "15B", I would like to consider only the "15" part) and insert it into a currently empty Field B that I have created.

How can I write a MS Access query that only considers the numeric portion of Field A and then inserts it into Field B?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pattern you described, you can build an update query with `like`, like this:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET tbl1.ValB = 
    Switch([ValA] Like "#[a-z]",Left([valA],1),
    [valA] Like "##[a-z]",Left([valA],2),True,NULL);
```

Or use the `Val` function, which will try to convert as much as possible from the string into a number:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET tbl1.ValB = 
iif(valA like "#[a-z]" or valA like "##[a-z]",val(ValA),NULL)
```

Comment: The first statement you provided worked like a charm. I haven't used switch statements or the Left/Right functions before. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need id field as well

```
Private Sub bntStart_Click()
    On Error GoTo err_trap

        Dim con As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rsLocal, rsLocal_Upd As ADODB.Recordset

        Dim sql_string As String
        Dim counter, numeric_value As Integer

        Set counter = 1

        sql_string = "SELECT * FROM TblTest"

        Set con = CurrentProject.Connection
        Set rsLocal = con.Execute(sql_string)

        If Not (rsLocal.BOF And rsLocal.EOF) Then
            rsLocal.MoveFirst
            While Not rsLocal.EOF
                If Len(ExtractNumber(rsLocal.Fields("FieldA")) > 0) Then
                    numeric_value = ExtractNumber(rsLocal.Fields("FieldA"))
                    sql_string = "UPDATE TblTerms SET FieldB = " & numeric_value & " WHERE id = " & counter
                    Set con = CurrentProject.Connection
                    Set rsLocal_Upd = con.Execute(sql_string)
                End If
                rsLocal.MoveNext
                counter = counter + 1
            Wend
        End If

        Set con = Nothing
        Exit Sub

    err_trap:
        MsgBox (Err.Description)
        Set con = Nothing

    End Sub

    Function ExtractNumber(str As Srting)
        Dim iCount As Integer, i As Integer
        Dim sText As String
        Dim lNum As String


        'Written by OzGrid Business Applications
        '[url]www.ozgrid.com[/url]

        'Extracts a number from a cell containing text And numbers.

        sText = str

        For iCount = Len(sText) To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Mid(sText, iCount, 1)) Then
                i = i + 1
                lNum = Mid(sText, iCount, 1) & lNum
            End If

            If i = 1 Then lNum = CInt(Mid(lNum, 1, 1))
        Next iCount

        ExtractNumber = CLng(lNum)
    End Function
```

Please be advised that I took the ExtractNumber from here http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=18185

Answer (score 1):

For the validation part of your question, you can use `Like` pattern-matching.  Here is an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
? "15A" Like "#[A-Z]" Or "15A" Like "##[A-Z]"
True

? "4B" Like "#[A-Z]" Or "4B" Like "##[A-Z]"
True

? "123A" Like "##[A-Z]" Or "123A" Like "##[A-Z]"
False

? "15AB" Like "#[A-Z]" Or "15AB" Like "##[A-Z]"
False

? "15!" Like "#[A-Z]" Or "15!" Like "##[A-Z]"
False
```

If those tests correctly express your intent, you could use this as the *Validation Rule* for `Field A`:

```sql
Like "#[A-Z]" Or Like "##[A-Z]"
```

As for `Field B`, you could make that a field expression in a query.

```sql
SELECT
    [Field A],
    Val([Field A]) AS [Field B]
FROM YourTable;
```

Use that query anywhere you need to see `[Field B]`.  With that approach, if `[Field B]` doesn't exist in your table, you needn't be concerned about updating `[Field B]` stored values whenever `[Field A]` values change.